# copy all files with certain extension

Tags: vb.net, file

Hello I want to copy all files with and a specific extension. I've tried a few things but it isn't working. During my debug I get an exception "Illegal characters used in path" I'm guessing it doesn't like *.xls any suggestions?

First try

```
 My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyFile("C:\test\test\mxw\*.xls\", "C:\workorder1-23\workorder1-23\mxw\", True)
```

second try

```
For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("C:\test\test\mxw\*.xls\", CStr(SearchOption.AllDirectories))
     If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(f.ToString) Then
          File.Copy("C:\test\test\mxw\*.xls\", "C:\workorder1-23\workorder1-23\mxw\", True)
     End If
Next
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CopyFile copies just one file.
You cannot use it with wildcards to copy a group of files.  (The invalid character is probably the wildcard)
And you should not append a backslash at the end of the file.

So let me try to replace your code with this

```
For Each f In Directory.GetFiles("C:\test\test\mxw", "*.xls", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
     If File.Exists(f) Then
          File.Copy(f, Path.Combine("C:\workorder1-23\workorder1-23\mxw", Path.GetFileName(f)), True)
     End If
Next
```

Also [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143316.aspx) has three parameters, a path, a pattern and a flag to read subfolders

Answer (score 0):

Since File.Copy does not create directories the provided answer will only work if the target directories exist. Add a Create.Directory(f) before the File.Copy if they don't.